# Xcopy to copy day -1 data

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

My current code is working fine for today's modified date, however now I want my code to copy day-1 data also along with today's data.

```
@ECHO OFF
  FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%V IN ("%DATE%") DO SET TDY=%%V
  xcopy /y "DATA_PATH" "LOCAL_SYSTEM" /d:%TDY%
  SET TDY=
```

Comment: use the [search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+get+yesterdays+date)

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your reply.....but I am new to xcopy & have no idea about search function

Comment: That's not a `xcopy`issue, you just need to get yesterdays date. Click on the blue words "search function" in my first comment. It leads you directly to the relevant threads.  You'll find many different ways to calculate it; choose one, that fits your needs best. Of course you can ask again, if you have trouble with it.

Comment: May be "search function" can easily solve my problem....but the thing is i seriously don't know hoe to play around with "search function"...sorry

Comment: hm - top right corner of this page? Use it similar to other search sites like google

Answer (score 1):

A way to get yesterday's Date using a BAT/VBS solution :

**Yesterday.bat**

```
@echo off
>yesterday.vbs echo wscript.echo DateAdd("d", -1, Date(^)^)

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript /nologo yesterday.vbs') do set "$yesterday=%%a"

Echo Yesterday'Date is ==^> %$Yesterday%
```

If you want to directly replace the `/` char by `-` for example :

**Yesterday.bat**

```
@echo off
>yesterday.vbs echo wscript.echo replace((DateAdd("d", -1, Date(^)^)^),"/","-"^)

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript /nologo yesterday.vbs') do set "$yesterday=%%a"

Echo Yesterday'Date is ==^> %$Yesterday%
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to download datex.exe:

```
For /f %%a in ('DateX -o -1 -f yyyymmdd') do Set "PreDate=%%a"
```

datex usage:

```
 4:12:56.76 c:\>datex /?
DateX 2.7 - (C) 2004-2010 by Bill Stewart (bstewart@iname.com)

Usage: datex [-d date] [-f format] [-i num] [-o offset] [-t]

-d  Specifies a date.
-f  Specifies the format for the date.
-i  Output the date represented by the specified number (inverse of -t).
-o  Specify a number-of-days difference.
-t  Output the date as a number for comparison purposes.

Without arguments, DateX prints the current date and time.
```